# Integration Limits for calculating Convolution

Tags: integration, convolution

[image: calculate convolution]

to calculate the convolution..
I know how to divide it into intervals. but i don't know how to set the integration limits. i 've been working on it for 10 hours and become wrong results. can anyone help?
what would be for example the integration limits for the interval [-0.5,0]

Comment: I have found the right way to solve the problem. the Limits can be calculated as in this website explained. follow the Link:
http://www.schlembach-verlag.de/pdf/283/Fliege_SuS_Leseprobe1.pdf  
a tool to help you visualise the convolution is in the following link:
https://maxwell.ict.griffith.edu.au/spl/Excalibar/Jtg/Conv.html

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question and accept it so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the right way to solve the problem. the Limits can be calculated as in this website explained. follow the Link: schlembach-verlag.de/pdf/283/Fliege_SuS_Leseprobe1.pdf a tool to help you visualise the convolution is in the following link: maxwell.ict.griffith.edu.au/spl/Excalibar/Jtg/Conv.html